# Pandas read_html to get href not text just for one column

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I'm trying to work with a table at a website. The fourth table in the website when I import with pandas read_html.

Using pandas.read_html I can get the data in a really easy and pretty way.

My issue is that I don't need the 'Download' text in the last column ('Arquivo'), but the href link to download instead.

Could someone help me to implement this exception?

I've seen some answers (like this one: [HTML table to pandas table: Info inside html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771619/html-table-to-pandas-table-info-inside-html-tags)), but I wasn't able to implement in my case.

here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = (pd.read_html('http://sisweb.tesouro.gov.br/apex/f?p=2501:2::::2::')[3])
print(df) #this way I print the table with 'Download' text.
```

And the second try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options() #I pretend to use headless, but I did not activate in this example. 
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu') 

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://sisweb.tesouro.gov.br/apex/f?p=2501:2::::2::')

bsobj = bs(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

tabela_geral = bsobj.findAll('table', {'class':'table table-striped'})

#this returns to me all the tables I want to work with. is this case, the table in the first (0)

import lxml.html as LH

table = LH.fromstring(str(tabela_geral[0])) #getting just the first return from selenium.

for df in pd.read_html(str(tabela_geral[0])):
    df['Arquivo'] = table.xpath('//tr/td/a/@href')
    print(df) #this returns me an error.
```

Tranks.

ps: MacOS High Sierra / Python 3.6

Comment: Use the `attrs={'id': '82502690936618670'}` to the `pd.read_html()` call - there are nested tables in that page, so use `pd.read_html(..., attrs={'id': '82502690936618670'})[0][3]`

Comment: I still got Download text instead of the link address. I tried  something like this (pd.read_html('http://sisweb.tesouro.gov.br/apex/f?p=2501:2::::2::', attrs={'id': '82502690936618670'})[0]) --- and this (pd.read_html('http://sisweb.tesouro.gov.br/apex/f?p=2501:2::::2::', attrs={'id': '82502690936618670'})[0][3])

Comment: you need the scheme `http://...`, it was in your original post, not sure why you would remove it.