# Dynamic web scrape with BeautifulSoup and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract HTML data from a table, which consists of about a thousand records, and each records only show 10 of them, thus there are many pages of that table. I have successfully combined Selenium and BeautifulSoup to loop through all the pages and extract the HTML data with for loop, however, when I tried to scrape for five pages of the table, the results shows the HTML data from the first page, being scraped 5 times, although Selenium did redirect the table to page 6.

Scenario:

I am trying to scrape NBA stars' names off the HTML table from the NBA site `https://www.nba.com/players`. It can be seen that there are 50 players on each page of the table. I want to scrape 100 names of NBA stars, which would require me to scrape the first 2 pages of the table.

My code is as below:

```
url = 'https://www.nba.com/players'
driver.get(url)
page = requests.get(url)
print(page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)

table = soup.table
table = soup.find(class_='players-list')
names[]
for pages in range(2):
    for names in table.find_all('tbody'):
        name_rows = names.find_all('tr')
        for name_row in name_rows:
            player_names = name_row.find('td', class_ = 'primary text RosterRow_primaryCol__1lto4').text
    names.append(player_names)
```

But the output I received contains the players' names on the first page scraped twice:

```json
['PreciousAchiuwa',
 'StevenAdams',
 'BamAdebayo',
 'OchaiAgbaji',
 'SantiAldama',
 'NickeilAlexander-Walker',
 'GraysonAllen',
 'JarrettAllen',
 'JoseAlvarado',
 'KyleAnderson',
 'GiannisAntetokounmpo',
 'KostasAntetokounmpo',
 'ThanasisAntetokounmpo',
 'ColeAnthony',
 'O.G.Anunoby',
 'RyanArcidiacono',
 'DeniAvdija',
 'DeandreAyton',
 'UdokaAzubuike',
 'IbouBadji',
 'MarvinBagley III',
 'PatrickBaldwin Jr.',
 'LaMeloBall',
 'LonzoBall',
 'MoBamba',
 'PaoloBanchero',
 'DesmondBane',
 'DalanoBanton',
 'DominickBarlow',
 'HarrisonBarnes',
 'ScottieBarnes',
 'RJBarrett',
 'WillBarton',
 'CharlesBassey',
 'KeitaBates-Diop',
 'NicolasBatum',
 'DariusBazley',
 'BradleyBeal',
 'MalikBeasley',
 'MarJonBeauchamp',
 'DavisBertans',
 'PatrickBeverley',
 'SaddiqBey',
 'KhemBirch',
 'GogaBitadze',
 'BismackBiyombo',
 'BuddyBoeheim',
 'BogdanBogdanovic',
 'BojanBogdanovic',
 'BolBol',
 'PreciousAchiuwa',
 'StevenAdams',
 'BamAdebayo',
 'OchaiAgbaji',
 'SantiAldama',
 'NickeilAlexander-Walker',
 'GraysonAllen',
 'JarrettAllen',
 'JoseAlvarado',
 'KyleAnderson',
 'GiannisAntetokounmpo',
 'KostasAntetokounmpo',
 'ThanasisAntetokounmpo',
 'ColeAnthony',
 'O.G.Anunoby',
 'RyanArcidiacono',
 'DeniAvdija',
 'DeandreAyton',
 'UdokaAzubuike',
 'IbouBadji',
 'MarvinBagley III',
 'PatrickBaldwin Jr.',
 'LaMeloBall',
 'LonzoBall',
 'MoBamba',
 'PaoloBanchero',
 'DesmondBane',
 'DalanoBanton',
 'DominickBarlow',
 'HarrisonBarnes',
 'ScottieBarnes',
 'RJBarrett',
 'WillBarton',
 'CharlesBassey',
 'KeitaBates-Diop',
 'NicolasBatum',
 'DariusBazley',
 'BradleyBeal',
 'MalikBeasley',
 'MarJonBeauchamp',
 'DavisBertans',
 'PatrickBeverley',
 'SaddiqBey',
 'KhemBirch',
 'GogaBitadze',
 'BismackBiyombo',
 'BuddyBoeheim',
 'BogdanBogdanovic',
 'BojanBogdanovic',
 'BolBol'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas and read html table, here a link how to,
[1]: https://pbpython.com/pandas-html-table.html, only need use bs4 for make request to url provided by you, and parse html data,

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I'm trying to scrape the href on each row of the table as well, is there any way to do that on pandas?

Comment: you can follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56757977/12852946

Comment: and this article can be useful for you https://towardsdatascience.com/all-pandas-read-html-you-should-know-for-scraping-data-from-html-tables-a3cbb5ce8274

Comment: Have taken a look on the links provided, the results I'm getting is still the repeat of the first page of results (first 50 names scraped twice), even for the links. Notable thing is that, even though the table moved to the second page, showing player names from 50-100, but BS4 still returns the information on the first page of the table.