# Is there a way to extract hyperlinks from a HTML table through Pandas?

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I am trying to scrap the T20I match summaries from 2005: [match-summaries](https://www.espncricinfo.com/records/year/team-match-results/2005-2005/twenty20-internationals-3)

Is there a way for me to scrap this table with the last Scorecard column values extracted as hyperlinks instead of the text using Pandas?

I came across this question in stackoverflow from about a year ago: [reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56757261/extract-href-using-pandas-read-html). The answers here used BeautifulSoup which isn't my preferred approach but it is fine if that's the easiest way to do it. However, that did not work for me.

I have even tried using the URLExtract library but it doesn't seem to work. I would like to do it using just Pandas directly without any use of HTML tags. I tried using the extract_links parameter of pandas.read_html but that gives both the text and link separated by commas which is not useful. There are other issues too with that method. I cannot extract only for a particular column using that: the options are all, header, footer and body. Also the link is printed partially broken so it cannot be used. This is my preferred approach if I am able to separate the link into a new column rather than appearing together with the associated text. I can solve the column specific issue by printing out only the scorecard column as a dataframe (with extracted links) and join it to the base table later.  Is there a way to separate the link from the text using extract_links? If I do this, I can then add the base prefix 'https://www.espncricinfo.com' to the link which would make it work. I have commented out the line using this approach in the code below.

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.espncricinfo.com/records/year/team-match-results/2005-2005/twenty20-internationals-3'
table = pd.read_html(url)[0]
#table = pd.read_html(url, extract_links = "body")[0]
table
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get links from the `<a>` tags, you can use `extract_links=` parameter and transform the dataframe next (add `base_url` for example):

```py
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.espncricinfo.com/records/year/team-match-results/2005-2005/twenty20-internationals-3'
base_url = 'https://www.espncricinfo.com'

table = pd.read_html(url, extract_links = "body")[0]
table = table.apply(lambda col: [v[0] if v[1] is None else f'{base_url}{v[1]}' for v in  col])
print(table)
```

Prints:

```
                                             Team 1                                           Team 2       Winner     Margin                                                     Ground    Match Date                                                                                                                                        Scorecard
0   https://www.espncricinfo.com/team/new-zealand-5    https://www.espncricinfo.com/team/australia-2    Australia    44 runs  https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/ground/58792.html  Feb 17, 2005         https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/australia-tour-of-new-zealand-2004-05-61407/new-zealand-vs-australia-only-t20i-211048/full-scorecard
1       https://www.espncricinfo.com/team/england-1    https://www.espncricinfo.com/team/australia-2      England   100 runs  https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/ground/57312.html  Jun 13, 2005      https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/australia-tour-of-england-and-scotland-2005-139019/england-vs-australia-only-t20i-211028/full-scorecard
2  https://www.espncricinfo.com/team/south-africa-3  https://www.espncricinfo.com/team/new-zealand-5  New Zealand  5 wickets  https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/ground/59120.html  Oct 21, 2005  https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/new-zealand-tour-of-south-africa-2005-06-212910/south-africa-vs-new-zealand-only-t20i-222678/full-scorecard
```